# Add user to ticket command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I coded this to add a user to a ticket channel, without checking if it's in a ticket channel, because it has a role condition (founder_role const):

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const SimplDB = require("simpl.db");
const db1 = new SimplDB();

module.exports = {
  name: "ticket-add-user",
  description: "[ADMIN ONLY] ",
  type: Discord.ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput,
  options: [
    {
        name: "user",
        description: "[ADMIN ONLY] ",
        type: Discord.ApplicationCommandOptionType.User,
        required: true,
    }
],

  run: async (client, interaction) => {
    const founder_role = db1.fetch(`founder_${interaction.guildId}`)
    const user_id = interaction.options.getUser('user').id;
    const user_m = interaction.options.getUser('user');

    if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(founder_role)) {
      interaction.reply({ content: `Sorry ${interaction.user}, but you are not allowed to use this command!`, ephemeral: true })
  } else {
    
    interaction.channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(
      {
        id: user_id,
        allow: [
          Discord.PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel,
          Discord.PermissionFlagsBits.SendMessages,
          Discord.PermissionFlagsBits.AttachFiles,
          Discord.PermissionFlagsBits.EmbedLinks,
          Discord.PermissionFlagsBits.AddReactions
        ]
      }
  );
    
    let embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
    .setAuthor({ name: interaction.guild.name, iconURL: interaction.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }) })
    .setFooter({ text: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }) })
    .setThumbnail(interaction.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))
    .setColor("Green")
    .setTitle(` Ticket Management `)
    .setDescription(`The founder/owner ${interaction.user} added the following user to this ticket:\n${user_m}.`);

    let error = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
    .setAuthor({ name: interaction.guild.name, iconURL: interaction.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }) })
    .setFooter({ text: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }) })
    .setThumbnail(interaction.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))
    .setColor("Green")
    .setTitle(` Ticket Management `)
    .setDescription(`The founder/owner ${interaction.user} tried to add a user to the ticket, but was not possible.`);

    interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] }).catch(e => {
      interaction.reply({ embeds: [error] })
    });
  }
}};
```

And received this error:

```
if (!userOrRole) throw new DiscordjsTypeError(ErrorCodes.InvalidType, 'parameter', 'User nor a Role');
                             ^

TypeError [InvalidType]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role.
    at PermissionOverwriteManager.upsert (C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\COISAS\discord-bot\doten-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\PermissionOverwriteManager.js:101:30)
    at PermissionOverwriteManager.edit (C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\COISAS\discord-bot\doten-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\PermissionOverwriteManager.js:150:17)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\COISAS\discord-bot\doten-bot\Commands\Tickets\adduser.js:27:46)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\COISAS\discord-bot\doten-bot\index.js:25:11)
    at Client.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\COISAS\discord-bot\doten-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:97:12)
    at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\COISAS\discord-bot\doten-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\COISAS\discord-bot\doten-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:352:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\COISAS\discord-bot\doten-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:494:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\COISAS\discord-bot\doten-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:328:10) {
  code: 'InvalidType'
}
```

Can someone please tell me what's wrong and what I need to replace, so it works?
I already submited the error into some foruns, but i couldn't get helped.

Comment: You will need to check/log the value of `user_id`.